# cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile on a simple setter

Tags: c++

I have a classical class containing basic attributes (strings and ints) and I made a setter on a string. 
The setter works well when I use it one time but when I use it two times in a row I get a cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile.

The setter is "repeindre".

Appartement.h

```
class Appartement
{
    // public:

    //Attributs
    int m_nombrePieces;
    int m_superficie;
    std::string m_couleurMur;
    std::string m_typeSol;

    public:

    std::string getCouleurMur();
    std::string setCouleurMur(std::string couleurMur);


    //constructeur
    Appartement(int nombrePieces, int superficie, std::string couleurMur, std::string typeSol);
}
```

Appartement.cpp

```
string Appartement::getCouleurMur()
{
    return m_couleurMur;
}


string Appartement::setCouleurMur(string couleurMur)
{
    m_couleurMur = couleurMur;
}



//constructeur
Appartement::Appartement(int nombrePieces, int superficie, string couleurMur, string typeSol) :
        m_nombrePieces(nombrePieces), m_superficie(superficie), m_couleurMur(couleurMur), m_typeSol(typeSol)
{
}
```

main.cpp

```
Appartement _5pieces(5,120,"bleue","carrelage");

cout << "description de l'appartement :" << endl;

std::string appart = _5pieces.description();

cout << appart << endl;

cout << "changement de couleur" << endl;

_5pieces.repeindre("jaune");

cout << "test" << endl;

appart = _5pieces.description();

cout << appart << endl;

cout << "peinture" << endl;

_5pieces.repeindre("vert");

appart = _5pieces.description();

cout << appart << endl;
```

Comment: You tell the compiler that the `setCouleurMur` function should return a `std::string`. But you don't actually return anything. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: By the way, your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is flawed, as it is not *complete*, nor does it actually call any of the functions you think you have problems with.